# Call Function in Java

Tags: java, android, function, android-listview

I'm beginner in Java.

Do you know what is wrong with this?

I have class ActivityToSmartWatch

```
public class ActivityToSmartWatch extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String[]> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public String[] inkLevels = new String[5];
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.PrinterStatus.AppLab.MESSAGE";



public ActivityToSmartWatch(Activity a, ArrayList<String[]> inkLevels) {
    activity = a;
    data = inkLevels;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Inside that I have GetInkLevel class

```
public String[] getInkLevel (String [] inkLevels, int position)
    {

        for (int i= 0; i <data.size(); i++)
        {
            System.arraycopy(data.get(position), 0, inkLevels, 0, data.get(position).length);

        }
        return inkLevels;
}
```

In another class I want to call it like this

```
 ActivityToSmartWatch A2SSW = new ActivityToSmartWatch(activity, data);
 A2SSW.getInkLevel(inkLevels, position);
```

I know that is wrong, do you know what mistake that I have made?

Comment: Is there a specific error message you are getting? The implementation looks alright at first glance.

Comment: `I know that is wrong` - how do you know? Exception?

Comment: What have you passed as parameters to the method getInkLevel() arguments?

Comment: post the logcat if its android specific tag with android

Comment: that's not how arrayCopy works. (which, by the way, you don't need in this case)

Answer (score 1):

`A2SSW` is an instance of `ActivityToSmartWatch` so it wouldn't have `getInkLevel`. You'll need to get hold of the `GetInkLevel` class to call its method. Your IDE will most likely inform you somehow that the method is not available.

Can you provide the full `ActivityToSmartWatch` class.

edit:

Are you using an array for inkLevels to represent the primary colours and black? It may be worth creating a [pojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class instead:

```
public class InkCartridge {
    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;
    private int black;

    public int getRed() {
        return red;
    }

    public void setRed(final int red) {
        this.red = red;
    }

    public int getGreen() {
        return green;
    }

    public void setGreen(final int green) {
        this.green = green;
    }

    public int getBlue() {
        return blue;
    }

    public void setBlue(final int blue) {
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    public int getBlack() {
        return black;
    }

    public void setBlack(final int black) {
        this.black = black;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("InkCartridge{");
        sb.append("red=").append(red);
        sb.append(", green=").append(green);
        sb.append(", blue=").append(blue);
        sb.append(", black=").append(black);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Rather than using `ArrayList<String[]>` it may be better to use `List<List<String>>`. Using Lists is generally better. If `inkLevels` was a list you could easily do handy thing like `inkLevels.get(index);` which seems to be what your `getInkLevel` should be doing based on the method name. While on the subject, it's worth mentioning that you should stick to known naming conventions. Variables and methods should always start with a lowercase character and if you intend to return an array then your method should be called getInkLevels not getInkLevel. Just because it compiles doesn't make it good code. [This book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) is a must read for any developer.

In the for loop it's cleaner to use this stlye: `for(Type item : collection) {` so if you had a list of string lists you'd use `for(List<String> list : data) {`

Comment: Whoops. Missed the point that GetInkLevel is a class in and of itself. Spot on.

Comment: Based on the constructor and instance variables, `getInkLevel` is indeed a method of `ActivityToSmartWatch`, OP just wrote class instead of method in the question. If `GetInkLevel` were its own class, the Constructor of `ActivityToSmartWatch` would make no sense. Thus your answer is probably completely wrong.

Comment: You're right I was looking at the code based on the fact that it stated there was an inner class of GetInkLevel. Looking at it again it seems his issue is that he calls the method but doesnt do anything with the returned value.

`String[] inkLevels = A2SSW.getInkLevel(inkLevels, position);`

Hard to tell when it's a poorly worded question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ActivityToSmartWatch A2SSW = new ActivityToSmartWatch(activity, data);
String[] inkLevels = new String[];
inkLevels = A2SSW.getInkLevel(inkLevels, position);
```

You created a string array but getInklevel returns a string array.
Hope this helped